# How to define a custom base of numbers in php?

Tags: php, numbers, radix

I need to define new number base for my custom calculations,

I have an order list of 11 chars (lets say a,h,k,d,e,f,g,z,i,j,m)
I want to to be able to perform mathematics tasks on them like they were a number base.
For example a+h=k, a+k=d, j++=m and etc...

Is this possible?

The best way I thought of is taking regular base of 11 and just replace all chars before and after the calculation it self (so j++ would be actually 9++=a and then a will be translated into m).
This way is not very efficient but will work.

Any better ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What's different from what you want to do and using regular variables or php [definitions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)?

Comment: I don't think you understood the question :)

I need a number base of ordered list (like 1 2 3 4 5 6... but with different characters), not just pre defined variables.

Comment: Perhaps not. By number base, are you referring to the base as in binary is base 2, octal is base 8, etc?

Comment: You can't use native PHP math functions with a custom base, with or without using custom characters. PHP only understands binary, octal, decimal and hexadecimal as integers, so you need to convert to one of those for math operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP offers to perform math operations for decimal, octal, hexadecimal and binary numbers natively. If you want to do calculations with other kinds of number systems you need to convert them to one of the above kinds.

Basically you are using a base11 number system - having custom digits. PHP offers the function `base_convert()` to convert numbers between systems with a different base. Having this, you just need to translate your custom digits to base11 then base11 to decimal then calculate and then convert it back.

Hackish!, but it can be done like this.

```
function add($a, $b) {
    $custom_digits = 'ahkdefgzijm';
    $base11_digits = '0123456789A';

    // translate custom numbers to base11
    $base11_a = strtr($a, $custom_digits, $base11_digits);
    $base11_b = strtr($a, $custom_digits, $base11_digits);

    // translate base11 numbers to decimal
    $decimal_a = base_convert($base11_a, 11, 10);
    $decimal_b = base_convert($base11_b, 11, 10);

    // Do the calculation
    $result = $decimal_a + $decimal_b;

    // Convert result back to base11
    $base11_result = base_convert($result, 10, 11);

    // Translate base11 result into customer digits
    return strtr($base11_result, $base11_digits, $custom_digits);
}
```

And never forget!:

```
h + h == k
```

:)

---

A more flexible attempt could be to create two functions like this:

```
function dec_to_custom($n) {
    static $custom_digits = 'ahkdefgzijm';
    static $base11_digits = '0123456789a';
    return strtr(base_convert($n, 10, 11), $base11_digits, $custom_digits);
}

function custom_to_dec($n) {
    static $custom_digits = 'ahkdefgzijm';
    static $base11_digits = '0123456789a';
    $base11 = strtr($n, $custom_digits, $base11_digits);
    return base_convert($base11, 11, 10);
}
```

And the use them like you wish in (integer!) math operations:

```
echo dec_to_custom(custom_to_dec(1) + custom_to_dec(1));
```

---

**Update**

Looks like I answered too fast. You had already a solution like I suggested and you are concerned about the `strtr()` usage. I can only say that I did a similar task once and did a lot of profiling and ended up using `strtr()` since it showed the best performance.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of my current solution.

If no better solution will be posted I will accept this.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid the `strtr` substitution approach, your only other option, on a quick thought, would be generating an array of all the numbers you may conceivably use, and then referencing that back and forth. Which would be even more hackish.

Comment: Hi! I want to accept your answer, please add @MarkusAO comment on top so it will technically answer my question " You can't use native PHP math functions with a custom base, with or without using custom characters. PHP only understands binary, octal, decimal and hexadecimal as integers, so you need to convert to one of those for math operations. –  Markus AO 52 mins ago "

Comment: Slower for sure. @hek2mgl you might as well mention binary alongside octal, decimal and hexadecimal. ~ "Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation, optionally preceded by a sign (- or +)." ~ http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: @hek2mgl Why are you using `static` in the second example?

Comment: @Alph.Dev Declared as `static`, the variables will only get initialized the first time the method is called. Since their values don't change, there is no need to initialize them again and again.